# How can I click on the <li class> element?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver

I want click the blue part for select at dropdown
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpTBd.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='selectbox-list']/li[2]")).click()
```

Just target 2nd li for .click() as an xpath.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
but i got bug.
<code>raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)

Comment: Try just using driver.find_element_by_xpath("").

Answer (score 0):

driver.find_element((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='ellipsis1']")).click()

It clicks the first element which is highlighted in your code